# Electron - Tidy Up Packaged App Folder

Tags: javascript, electron

Running electron-packager, I expected the resulting folder structure to be a bit neater, so that I could just zip it up and allow it to be downloaded as an app.

The main folder contains the executable app, but also a lot of .dll, .pak and .bin files.  I think this may be a bit confusing to users of my app, is there any way to move all of these files into a folder when running electron packager?

Answer (score 0):

The output from `electron-packager` is not supposed to be used by the user. It gives an output folder that you can pass into the [windows installer](https://github.com/electron/windows-installer) to make an installer for users. The installer hides that messy folder under `AppData\Local\appname\app-version`. It uses [Squirrel](https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows) to do this and once configured correctly the user only sees desktop and start menu shortcuts to launch the application. Using Squirrel means it plays nicely with the Electron [autoUpdater](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/auto-updater.md).

While using the windows installer and auto updater is recommended you could also create a shortcut to the executable created by the packager so that users don't have to see the messy folder themselves.